# print 5 random key/value pairs from a javascript object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to select & print 5 random key/value pairs from a javascript object. Currently I iterate through the object like this:

```
        $.each(object, function(key, val) {
                 ...
        });
```

But how could I print 5 random key value pairs from this object ? The problem is that I dont know the length of this object so I could not do it by calculating a random start position & fetching 5 pairs starting from there.

Comment: I've added a jQuery tag. If that's not your framework, please re-tag accordingly.

Comment: thanks i forgot to mention that!

Comment: In each step of the iteration you can generate a random number between one and object length... and then get the value at that index

Comment: as I said I also dont know the object length..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finding the number of items in an object is not hard. You just need to use `Object.keys`. This gets an array containing all the key names from the object.

```
var keys = Object.keys(object),
    length = keys.length;
```

You would probably then want to choose items at random, perhaps like this:

```
var i,
    result = [];
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    result.push(object[keys[Math.floor(Math.random() * length)]]);
}
```

Comment: i came across `Object.keys. ` but that's not a cross browser solution. http://kangax.github.com/es5-compat-table/

Comment: @user01 [You can add it easily enough](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys#Compatibility).

Comment: @lonesomeday I've fixed the documentation to match your link anchor :)

Comment: @Jack Ha, I guess that's one way to do it!

Comment: @lonesomeday: I believe the link you pasted was meant for firefox support alone. Isn't it?

Comment: @user01 No, it's Javascript that will add an `Object.keys` function to any browser that doesn't implement it natively.

Answer (score 0):

`Object.keys(object)` will give you an array of all the keys in an object

```
var arrayOfAllKeys = Object.keys(object);
for(var i=0; i<5; i++){
    var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random()*arrayOfAllKeys.length);
    var objKey = arrayofAllKeys[rnd];
    alert( "key: " + objKey + " value: " + object[objKey]);
}
```

you can simulate the Object.keys(object) with:

```
var arrayOfKeys = [];
$.each(object, function(key, value){
    arrayOfKeys.push(key);
}
```

Comment: i came across `Object.keys. ` but that's not a cross browser solution. http://kangax.github.com/es5-compat-table/

Comment: @user01 i've updated my answer to make a "costume" object.key() function. That way you can get the array of keys in any browser

Answer (score 0):

If the object is not too large, you can copy data into a regular array and shuffle it:

```
function fisherYates(array){
    var i=array.length;
    while(i--){
        var j=Math.floor( Math.random() * (i+1) );
        var tmp=array[i];
        array[i]=array[j];
        array[j]=tmp;
    }
}

var object = {
    firstName: "Jim",
    lastName: "Smith",
    city: "London",
    country: "UK",
    age: 33,
    height: 170,
    score: 123,
    active: true
}

var deck = [];
$.each(object, function(key, val){
    var o = {};
    o[key] = val;
    deck.push(o);
});

fisherYates(deck);

var selection = deck.slice(0, 5);
console.log(selection);
```